# Site logo in "Bounty Grace Period Started" email is distorted

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, email, logo

The logo of the site where the bounty question is asked appears to be distorted in comparison to the text, when reading the mail:

> [image]

Same issue in landscape orientation.

Comment: I don't understand, what's the bug? The logo? Is it because it has BETA next to it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Maybe it's the squishedness of the logo?

Comment: @AndrewLi right, it’s squished horizontally.

Comment: Shouldn't you explain it in the report? Just a screenshot is a bit bare.

Comment: Oops! I was confusing Beta with Meta.

Comment: This squishes the Meta logo the other way: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318094/new-logo-in-bounty-email-is-squished-vertically It looks like they have set fixed height and width.

Comment: It's also an older-style logo: today, the word "beta" is capitalized as "Beta", and the color of that word is different.

Comment: I've put this in our bug queue.  Heights and widths were imposed so we could do 2x rendering with mobile devices, but we're highly inconsistent in sizing here.  Some sites use LogoEmail.png, others Logo.png.  Both of these are poorly maintained since we moved to Logo.svg, which we can't use in emails.  We're going to have to look at generating consistent and up-to-date LogoEmail.png files for all sites, possibly with a fixed height and variable width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now resolved. All of the site logos should now maintain their aspect ratio when shown in email headers.

---

> site sends an email
> aspect ratio OK
> for header logo